# Disallow System.Net tracing

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, ssl

I have a client app that communicates over SSL.

The RESTful web service needs to only answer request that originate from legitimate sources.

An authentication key is sent as a rudimentry security measure, encrypted into the app thanks to Obfuscar. All of this can be reverse engineered, with a moderate skill level. I do have other *top secret measures* in place

However one very simple approach I've just discovered would make life very easy for a casual hacker - enable System.Net tracing using the app.config. This allows all http traffic to be logged, pre-tls encryption.

How can I progmatically disable, turn off, or disallow, the System.Net trace or even just all tracing?

Comment: Instead of a static key use a challenge-response system so you aren't vulnerable to replay-attacks, then it won't matter if they see the unencrypted payload.

Comment: Thanks. I did more reading. Problem is, it's restful.  I don't think I can challenge every single rest request. Everything I read tends to say 'just use SSL and you're done'. But that doesn't take into account snooping in on the memory of the client. And this is essentially what tracing allows.

Comment: That is because everything is the threat model of protecting from a Man In The Middle (MITM) attack, but you don't have that threat model. You have what boils down to a DRM problem. Go research DRM solutions, that might give you more of what you need. Also, look in to how [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) does it's authentication. It hashes the header with a client secret that the client and server share. If someone gets the decrypted copy of the hash they still can't reverse the hash to  get the client secret because hashes are non-reverseable.

Comment: DRM - yeah true, was just starting to think that. I knew the over all security is a bigger issue. The question was just about disabling such a simple hack.

Comment: For now I'll settle with hashing the url (hmac??). At least a hacker won't be able to make misc requests.

Comment: Are any parts of those *top secret measures* distributed to others?  On their machines, that you have *no* control over?

Comment: Clients must be registered in the server. We control the server. So, fairly big plus there. I'm probably being over zealous to be honest.